# Futuro semplice del verbo possedere: con la "i" o senza?

Tags: verbs

Nel verbale di una riunione un mio collega ha scritto *possiederanno*, io pensavo si dicesse *possederanno*.
Su WordReference ci sono entrambe le versioni:
http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=possedere

Qual è quella più corretta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordReference, personalmente, lo lascerei perdere, ma effettivamente i dizionari veri affermano che sono ammesse entrambe le possibilità.

Per la precisione, lo Zingarelli, nella tavola della coniugazione, dà la doppia versione «essi possederànno, possiederànno» (e lo stesso per tutte le altre persone del futuro), mentre il Treccani per la coniugazione rimanda al verbo “sedere”, e [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sedere2/), dopo aver dato alcune forme specifiche, conclude:

> le altre forme sono regolari, senza il dittongo: *sedévo*, *sedéssi*, *seduto*, ecc.; nel fut. e condiz. si tende oggi, spec. nella lingua parlata, a usare le forme dittongate: *siederò*, *siederèi*

Quindi la versione tradizionale omette il dittongo (“[pos]sederò”), coerentemente con il fatto che il “dittongo mobile” cade quando non è accentato.

Comment: Per quello che vale, confermo che anche il Devoto-Oli dà la doppia coniugazione.